# default value in es6 doesn't work with arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
handleSuccessFeatureListing = (selectedOption=7) => {
    console.log(selectedOption);
}
```

Why selectedOption still can be null? I thought I already set 7 as the default value for the param of selectedOption?

Comment: *"Why selectedOption still can be null?"* Can you be more specific? If you'd pass `null` then that's the value you get (because `null` is a value too). Only if you don't pass anything or pass `undefined` will the default value be used.

Comment: It is set to `7` https://es6console.com/j271v9nd/

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default values only come into affect if the function is called with no argument, or with an `undefined` value. If `handleSuccessFeatureListing` is called with `null`, `null` will be passed through.

e.g.

```
function fn(arg = 7){
  return arg;
}

fn() === 7
fn(undefined) === 7
fn(6) === 6
fn(null) === null
```

so if you are getting a `null`, then it is because `null` is being passed to the function when you expected an `undefined` value.